# Why can Discovery transport the tardigrade at the end of the show when at the start the shielding prevented them?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-transporter, star-trek-discovery, spore-drive

In [Star Trek Discovery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Discovery) [S1:E3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_Is_for_Kings) *Context is for Kings* we see the [USS Glenn](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Glenn), which contains the [mycelial plane](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Spore_drive) experiments and dead crew.

We learn (from [Saru](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Saru)) that it is not possible to [transport](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Transporter) the experiments to the discovery due to *lab shielding*, so the crew will have to go across to the USS Glenn.

At the end of the episode, the tardigrade has been transported to the [USS Discovery](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Discovery).

Indeed, the following commentator [writes](https://twitter.com/Theresa/status/920382356459888640):

> In this ep, Saru says the shielding of the test lab on the Glenn prohibits using the transporter to retrieve the project materials. yet we see the *guest* on board at the end

My question is: **Why can Discovery transport the tardigrade at the end of the show when at the start the shielding prevented them?**

Comment: The lab means just the room where they were cornered by tartigrade, and by equipment he meant hardware. Tartigrade itself was beamed out after it left the lab.

Comment: @Peters And of course this leads to the secondary question; why not beam it out as soon as it leaves the lab, rather than let it chase the away team around the ship (I have a feeling the answer will be "because that would be boring")

Comment: @user20310 maybe their shuttle didn't have a transporter?

Comment: Thanks @Petersaber could you expand that into an answer?

Comment: @hawkeye if a tech guide or something like that ever comes out (for Discovery) and confirms that, I will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lab is probably shielded for the very same reason why you would shield your warp-core. You don't want an enemy beaming out your core or precious research once your main shields go down.

Therefore they cannot beam out the experiments directly. But the tardigrade creature does not reside in the shielded room anymore and thus can be transported.